# form <that vs where>

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> Long before reading and writing became widely spread and available, oral storytelling had already been a form **where/that** the wisdom and knowledge of the people were passed down from elders to children. A good story engages our curiosity, emotions and imagination.

An artificial intelligence told me that "that" or "where" can be used here. I want to make sure of this, because I haven't seen a similar case of using "that" after "form" before.

Comment: Don't trust AI. **In which** or **whereby** would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better with a verb phrase, such as "for passing down..." Here's my edited version:

*Long before reading and writing became widespread, oral storytelling had been the form **for passing down** wisdom and knowledge from elders to children.*

If you want to use a that/which type phrase, there's this:

*Long before reading and writing became widespread, oral storytelling had been the form **through which** wisdom and knowledge were passed down from elders to children.*